# How do I programmatically hide and show parts of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext, adobe, acrobat

I have a PDF with several form fields that I want to programatically create or remove, depending on what the user has inputted. For example, the form may need a collection of fields that represent a transaction, but the user may have more than one transaction that needs to be entered, or possibly none at all. How can I ensure that the PDF removes parts of the page that are unneeded, or inserts parts of the page when certain conditions are met? The current tools I can use are iTextSharp and Adobe Acrobat DC, but if those aren't viable options, I can use an alternative as long as it's free. Thank you.

```
// An example of what I'd like to do:
for (int i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) 
{
// Insert title text (transaction i)
// Insert transaction field
// Insert transaction amount field
}
```

Comment: To a certain degree you can make pdf forms somewhat dynamic using javascript and showing and hiding previously defined fields. But trying to do completely dynamic tables that way means quite a lot of coding, probably more than you want to do. You can use itext to inject the javascript into the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter states, it is possible, but it can be a bit messy… You can create, move and resize fields (and it will be all fields, be assured). You will also use Template pages to be able to add and remove pages, as you will be responsible for the pagination of the document.

In any case, you will have to have a very good look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, and you will have to build up the knowledge on your own.

It will be a challenge, but it is feasible, as yours truly has shown it, and some of such forms were in productive use.